# ImageDownloader for Optik Swift

Tags: swift, swift-protocols

I am trying to use `Optik` library to display remote images from `URLs` in my `Swift app`.

On `Optik` documentation they say it's required a so called `imageDowloader parameter` like that:

```
let imageDownloader = MyImageDownloader()

let imageViewer = Optik.imageViewer(
    withURLs: [
        NSURL(string: "https://somewebsite.com/image1.png")!,
        NSURL(string: "https://somewebsite.com/image2.png")!,
        NSURL(string: "https://somewebsite.com/image3.png")!
    ],
    imageDownloader: imageDownloader
)

presentViewController(imageViewer, animated: true, completion: nil)
```

That `imageDownloader` parameters requires a `ImageDownloader protocol` that looks like that:

```
public protocol ImageDownloader {
    
    /**
     Downloads image from specified URL.
     
     - parameter url:        URL to download image from.
     - parameter completion: Callback handler that gets invoked after the download is complete.
     */
    func downloadImage(from url: URL, completion: @escaping ImageDownloaderCompletion)
    
}
```

**My question is:**

How I am supposed to send that `imageDownloader` variable into the function? How should `MyImageDownloader` looks like?

I tried to define it like `imageDownloader = ImageDownloader.self` but it doesn't work.

Thank you for your time!

Comment: So does MyImageDownloader conform to the protocol? Also, I checked out the project on GitHub and it hasn’t been updated for 3 years and seems to lack any documentation apart from the read me file, perhaps you could find something better or use the built in frameworks?

Comment: yes, that's what should do, `imageDownloader variable` should conform the `ImageDownloader protocol` but i don't know how to do that

Comment: If you don’t know how to conform to a protocol then you need to learn the basics of Swift but if it is for this specific case you are lost then I can’t help you since I don’t know the library, to me it looks like you need to implement the download functionality yourself. As I hinted before, you are probably better of ditching this library and use the standard tools.